# Subversion Command Line CLient with Windows Integrated Security?

Tags: svn

We use a SVN repository hosted on a website, accessed via http.

We use tortoise for normal operations and it works nicely. I never get asked for a password.

Now, for automated processing, some SVN retrieves have to happen in a batch script - and the problem is that the only svn client that supports command line that I am aware of does not seem to support integrated security, which means depositing the password somewhere, which means monthly changes of another file when the password changes. Painful.

Is there any SVN command line client available somewhere (where?) that could use windows integrated security when acessing a http svn repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tortoise svn *can* be run on the command line, [here are the tortoise docs on command line operation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)